# Get error "Expression has changed after it was checked" when using pristine and valid flags

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-forms, angular4-forms

In the Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/forms) I found [an example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/dnbvvqqbvjvm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhero-form%2Fhero-form.component.html) of using pristine and valid flags. But when I assign them to the properties of the component, I get an error "`Expression has changed after it was checked`". Why is this happening? And how can you solve this problem?

You can see [an example](https://github.com/dxvladislavvolkov/textbox_example)

Comment: check answer, if you can give more code i can go and check more detail

Comment: You can see an example from the angular documentation. And there I do not get an error. But if you run my example, you'll find an error if you enter a value into the second input

Answer (score 1):

There is problem with your code that you are trying to modify attribute `isValid` by checking same control pristine, it will give you error

```
   <text-box
        formControlName="emailControl"
        [(ngModel)]="formData.email"
        [isValid]="emailControl.pristine">
    </text-box>
```

basically you are trying to modify the value of control by control it self, and that is causing problem and giving you error.

You can check this, I created my own control for validation things check here :
[**Angular Custom Validation Component**](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2018/03/custom-validation-component.html), this might meet your requirement.

---

You are getting error because you are binding values with the html controls, and this values get changed during change detection cycle of angular. Mostly this error occurs when property values of `ParentComponent` get changed by `ChildComponent`.

on solution to come out it force change detection from parent component like this

```
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.cd.detectChanges();
    }
    //rest of the code 
}
```

check this : [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Comment: Should I call this method inside a custom component?

Comment: @vlado - yes , that need to be parent one , i hope you get my point

Comment: @vlado - can you share code whatever you tried , on stackbiz

Comment: You can see an example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b9hhcn?file=app%2Ftextbox.ts

Comment: @vlado - check my update, i created custom component and shared that also with you as link

Comment: Does this mean that I can not use these flags for options? I do not need this for validation. I added this option for example only

Comment: you can do like this <div *ngIf="emailControl.pristine"> control modified </div> ... if you want to check , right now you are modifying binding property that is causing problem ..if you can check my implementation i did what i suggested for showing error

Comment: I tried to ask a question on github. I got this answer: "You should don't mix template based form with reactive based one".

Comment: @vlado - yeah , just got it as you are using both `formControlName="emailControl"
        [(ngModel)]="formData.email"` it also cause problem

Comment: @vlado - but the error you are facing is because of you are modifying values which you should modify during angular changedetection cycle

Comment: I tried to make two examples. The first one was based on the form and there I used the ngModel. And everything works well.
In the second I based on the reactive form. And set values using setValue method. This also works without error.

Maybe there are problems with bindings option when using ngModel in reactive form?

Comment: @vlado - ngModel  is related to Template driven form , you should not use when you are using Reactive form approch, as in reactive form you create form by yourself in code part and use it for getting and modifying value , in case of template deiven form ngmodel directive take care of modifying

Comment: @vlado - if you got to article link i given , i provided both in seperate way means i provided seperate example for Template driven form and reactive form apporch

Comment: so the solution to this problem is "not to use the form with reactive forms"?